# Problem installing pymongo for Python 2.6

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, python-2.6, pymongo

I upgraded from OSX5 to OSX6, which comes with Python 2.6. I then had to install pymongo again to work with Python 2.6, but I'm having trouble doing it. When I run easy_install or pip it keeps installing pymongo in the python 2.5 directory... see terminal output below. Can anyone help? How do install pymongo for Python 2.6? Thanks!

```
localhost:~ $ sudo easy_install -U setuptools
Password:
Searching for setup tools
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools/
Reading http://peak.telecommunity.com/snapshots/
Best match: setuptools 0.6c12dev-r88846
Processing setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.6.egg
  setuptools 0.6c12dev-r88846 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/bin
Installing easy_install-2.6 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for setuptools
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools localhost:~

$ python -m easy_install pymongo
Searching for pymongo
Best match: pymongo 2.0
Adding pymongo 2.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pymongo
Finished processing dependencies for pymongo
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate Python 2.6 as the "current" version of Python. [This post at superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/35256/how-can-i-change-the-default-python-version-on-snow-leopard) explains how.

After that, you should be able to install pymongo using `easy_install`